# Can't load Python in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I am following a tutorial developing a Python plugin in QGIS. After completing the script for the plugin I got the following message the next time I started QGIS. Warning I am a complete novice with Python programming if this is the issue

Couldn't load PyQGIS.
Python support will be disabled.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis__init__.py", line 26, in 
    from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
ImportError: No module named PyQt

Comment: Which tutorial are you following? Was it written for QGIS3? Note that QGIS3 uses Python3 and all old tutorials are for Python2 and therefore won't work.

Comment: how did you install qgis, did you include python in the install

Comment: Its QGIS by Example by Packt Publishing. It was written for 2.8. Python was working fine in QGIS. I had some script wrong in the plugin, changed it and now can't load python in QGIS